How can I write my C code so the resulting ASM uses instructions that load smaller data chunks?
I'm decompiling a PS2 game that was shipped as a debug build. To verify that my C code matches the original, I compile it using the compiler that was originally used (Metrowerks CodeWarrior), disassemble the ELF file, then compare the disassemblies.
After finding the right version of said compiler, I'm close to matching the disassemblies exactly. What's still eluding me is the initialisation of local arrays.
This is the original ASM:
lui          a3,hi(@113+259)
addiu        a3,a3,lo(@113+-12800)
addiu        a2,sp,160
li           a1,4
lw           a0,0(a3)
lw           v1,4(a3)
addiu        a3,a3,8
addiu        a1,a1,-1
sw           a0,0(a2)
sw           v1,4(a2)
addiu        a2,a2,8
bgtz         a1,*-28

This is supposed to match the following C code at the top of a function:
int_union* patsettbl[8] =
{
  0,
  &scra_h_posit,
  &scrb_h_posit,
  &scrc_h_posit,
  0,
  &scra_v_posit,
  &scrb_v_posit,
  &scrc_v_posit
};

But when I compile it, I get the following ASM:
lui          v1,hi(@112+259)
addiu        v1,v1,lo(@112+-13568)
addiu        a1,sp,160
lq           a0,0(v1)
lq           v1,16(v1)
sq           a0,0(a1)
sq           v1,16(a1)

As you can see, it uses instructions that load bigger chunks of data to populate the array instead of loading smaller ones inside a loop.
I've been told this behaviour depends on the compiler. But I know for a fact that they used CodeWarrior, because the debug info has a string that says: "MW MIPS C Compiler (2.4.1.01).PlayStation2".
All optimisations are off when compiling.
Does anyone know what I could be doing wrong?
If it helps, here's a scratch: https://decomp.me/scratch/8RF78

This sounds like some sort of optimization that you might be able to turn off. Examine available compiler flags to see if any could be relevant. Also maybe your C code is simply not that? Could very well be an explicit table that is just copied in a for loop that your decompiler optimized?

For doing the same work without a loop it must(?) be using 128-bits at a time (2x128=the same 256 bits moved by the loop of 4x2x32-bits), i.e. some vectors registers?  Maybe can disable that with some option to turn off vector registers/instructions??

All optimisations are off.

The original C code probably used a loop to explicitly copy from a constant. I suspect that your "debug build" is in fact a release build just with debug info. At least on decomp.me I had to enable -O2 but with that the below code produces identical assembly:
static int_union* init[8] =
{
  0,
  &scra_h_posit,
  &scrb_h_posit,
  &scrc_h_posit,
  0,
  &scra_v_posit,
  &scrb_v_posit,
  &scrc_v_posit
};

void foo()
{
    int_union* patsettbl[8];
    int_union** src = init;
    int_union** dst = patsettbl;
    int i = 4;
    do
    {
        int_union* tmp0 = src[0];
        int_union* tmp1 = src[1];
        src += 2;
        i--;
        dst[0] = tmp0;
        dst[1] = tmp1;
        dst += 2;
    } while(i > 0);
}

Disclaimer: I don't really think the original code was actually this, rather, something that got optimized to this.

The debug build contains complete debug info (save for aliases of structs and unions), which is how I know that patsettbl is an array of 8 pointers to a union. It's not loading from a constant either, because in that case I'd have its name and type instead of a numeric identifier prepended by an at-sign.

Your debug info can tell otherwise but it does not change the fact that lw is a load word from memory. There is not even a constant 0 in the code. It is not doing patsettbl[0] = 0 it is doing patsettbl[0] = init[0]. And it does that looping 4 times setting 2 items per iteration which is a strong indication that it's a struct or maybe a 2D array. You can even find the initializer table in memory at address a3.

I know it's an lw, and the reason I'm asking this question is because I don't know how to recreate this initialisation behaviour. As @113 (which is what a3 points to) is a nameless part of the data section, I have no idea how I'd create a loop that pulls data from something that, to the program, doesn't exist. Also, I see you've mentioned that the code would be optimised to what I'm seeing, but that doesn't make sense, because, like I said, this is a debug build. No optimisations.

All I can say is the code in the answer with -O2 exactly matches your assembly.

Using -O2 indeed works for this initialisation. But as a result the rest of the function it's a part of no longer matches. It's definitely not a release build with debug info. The ASM as a whole is just too unoptimised for that to be the case. The only way I see this working is if the loop can somehow be written without using local variables.

The only idea I have for that is to make the compiler create a copy but even then to have it loop 4 times instead of 8 is a problem (if we stick to the 1D array)
